# Multi threading functions with locks and delays inside infinite loop in python 3.x

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x

I'm trying to run several functions every so many minutes or days on an infinite loop. These functions call data from an API and process the data (making data frames and writing to files).

To do this I'm trying to use multithreading inside a `while True:` loop of several functions that each contain the API call and data processing of the associated response. Each function has a different loop delay and the API has a call rate limit of 1 call per second.

Is this the correct approach to achieve my goal?

Please all suggestions, tips, corrections, warnings etc. It's easy to find very basic examples of multithreading, but harder to find anything just a little bit more complex than basic.

Here is a simplified version of my code (to demonstrate structure rather than being 100% correct):

```
import requests
import time
import threading
#... other imports

api = "https://..."
api_lock = threading.Lock()

def A():
    url = "abc"
    api_lock.acquire()
    response = requests.get(api+url)
    time.sleep(1)        #to avoid api call limit
    api_lock.release()
    #processing response (making dataframes and writing to files)
    time.sleep(300)

def B():
    url = "ghi"
    api_lock.acquire()
    response = requests.get(api+url)
    time.sleep(1)
    api_lock.release()
    #processing response (making dataframes and writing to files)
    time.sleep(180)

def C():
    url = "jkl"
    api_lock.acquire()
    response = requests.get(api+url)
    time.sleep(1)
    api_lock.release()
    #processing response (making dataframes and writing to files)
    time.sleep(86400) # 1 day

def combined():

    t_A = threading.Thread(target = A)
    t_A.start()
    if t_A.is_alive() == False:
         print('Will check A again in 5 min...')

    t_B = threading.Thread(target = B)
    t_B.start()
    if t_B.is_alive() == False:
        print('Will check B again in 3 min...')

    for i in range (50):
        t_C = threading.Thread(target = C,args=(i,))
        t_C.start()
    if t_C.is_alive() == False:
        print('Will check C again tomorrow...')

while True:
    combined()
```

Comment: are you intending to spin up 50 threads calling the C function?  what you want to do is have each function have a loop in it and its delay.  that way you will wait in that loop until its time to call that api again.  your current code will rip through the loop continuously creating thousands of threads quickly (probably resulting in exhaustion of resources.

Comment: you would want to likely call combined 1 time.  and as I said stay looping in the functions putting out the print saying your waiting to call it again. you may need to indefinitely sleep in the main path to allow the threads to keep running. often when spinning up a thread its put in a list of threads and then a loop is run taking the threads in turn and waiting for them to exit (using the join() function.)  when you finish iterating on the array you can then leave the main method.  in your case you never will because you want to stay in the loops in the threads.

Comment: The long sleeps (300 sec, 180 sec, etc) aren't working (not entirely sure why) and indeed the main program would have to run indefinitely. For these reasons I've made the very "non-pythonic" decision to do the scheduling via **cron** on the raspberry pi.

Comment: The problem you have is that your missing that the threads run *independent* of the main thread that started them.  so once the main does the .start() call it can move along to the next statement after the start while the function called via the thread gets run in parallel.   The result is you never wait in your main thread and you keep spawning threads that run without delay because of the while true loop.   Just spawn the threads ONCE and then loop in each of the functions so that the delay in the function is part of its loop.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your missing that the threads run independent of the main thread that started them. so once the main does the .start() call it can move along to the next statement after the start while the function called via the thread gets run in parallel. The result is you never wait in your main thread and you keep spawning threads that run without delay because of the while true loop. Just spawn the threads ONCE and then loop in each of the functions so that the delay in the function is part of its loop. Hope this helps